# Retrieve xbox live gamertag after login

Tags: php, live, xbox360, xbox

I want to login in my website with a verified gamertag by XBOX Live.

So I think I have two chances:

- use the openId ( and web auth API ) offered by Microsoft, but I can only retrieve user's real name, and I don't know how to retrieve the real gamertag
- implement by myself a login with Curl on live.com ( quite hard due to the high number of parameters, among other things, they are javascript generated.. )

Does anyone know any solution?

PS: my website is in PHP, but any resource is welcome

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need the user to provide you with the gamer tag and use that to authenticate.

**UPDATE**

Reading through [here](https://www.xboxleaders.com/#example-profile), i don't see any authentication support. All calls are based on the gamertag that is provided.

Comment: if he provides only the gamertag, there is no authentication, he could simply pretend to be someone

Comment: he should provide the gamertag and password

Comment: really? which is the endpoint? does any API that accept gamertag and password exist?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use OAuth 2.0 with Live, since Xbox us endorsed with Live (Microsoft) they use the same platform for signing in.

The biggest issue is there is no official documents on doing this - only Xbox and affiliates have information regarding scopes and endpoints.

Your best bet is to reverse engineer something like Smart-Glass and pay close attention to the HTTP requests that are being sent and re-engineer the cURL requests.

First step is to register an App on Live so you can request to use data.